# Can't get skydome image to appear

Tags: 12.04, compiz

In compiz, when I select an image for the skydome it doesn't appear when I rotate the cube. I have JPEG enabled, and the skydome box is checked, but when I go to rotate the cube it's just the default blue and white background. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that the image path is valid, and it is in the JPEG format. If it is, then first if you are using unity, log out of it, and use another desktop session (such as unity 2D). If compiz is the window manager for that session, temporarily use another one (such as xfwm4 or metacity). Then run the following commands in a terminal window:

```
rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/compiz*
rm -rf ~/.cache/compizconfig-1/
rm -rf ~/.config/compiz-1/
rm -rf ~/.compiz*
```

And then log out and log back in. See if this helps!

**Source**: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11436939&postcount=12